# What code will activate directions or street view in Google Maps within eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-street-view, directions

Does anyone know of a guide or code that will take an app user to Google maps, and input their latitude and longitude along with their targets after they pressed a given button? (Basically a directions feature)

Also, does anyone know of a guide or code that can take the user to the street view after they pressed a given button? (To show the user what the place looks like)

I've been looking for a guide for a while, and I can't find anything. IDK if it's just that I'm not typing the right thing in Google. So, any help will be welcomed.

Comment: you mean open googlemap app??

Comment: Google Maps. Within App Inventor, I was able to have a button called directions start the activity starter, and put out https://www.google.com/maps?saddr= (and it will find the lat and long of the user) &daddr= (lat and long of the target location). If the person had Google Maps then it would've open it up with the right in already in place. It would open up google maps with the right info within a website if they didn't have it.

Comment: By using this method, I had another button called Street View. This would do the same, but instead of looking for the persons location. It would just put in the link for the street view of the target area. It would open up in Google maps if they had it, or the browser if they didn't. Again, I'm trying to figure out how to do this within eclipse.

Comment: Here is a picture of the code within App Inventor. https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7740b4p0tv74ci/Untitled.png

Obviously this code is useless when you're looking at Java and XML.